# using localStorage with javascript objects and or arrays and or object arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

My app uses an array to store "friend" information:

```
var friends = new Array();
```

Each "friend" item has a name, a color, and list of entries stored as a JSON object.

In it's most crude form I'm doing this:

```
friends[0] = '{"name":"Fred","color":"rgb(255, 0, 0)","entries":"[{"time":"xxxx","desc":"Party"},{"time":"yyyy","desc":"Shopping"},{"time":"zzzz","desc":"Dinner"}]}';
friends[1] = '{"name":"George","color":"rgb(0, 255, 0)","entries":"[{"time":"qqqq","desc":"Car Pool"},{"time":"vvvv","desc":"Spa Treatment"},{"time":"wwww","desc":"Shopping"}]}';
```

EDIT:

I also tried it without the '' around the JSON, like this:

```
friends[0] = {"name":"Fred","color":"rgb(255, 0, 0)","entries":"[{"time":"xxxx","desc":"Party"},{"time":"yyyy","desc":"Shopping"},{"time":"zzzz","desc":"Dinner"}]};
friends[1] = {"name":"George","color":"rgb(0, 255, 0)","entries":"[{"time":"qqqq","desc":"Car Pool"},{"time":"vvvv","desc":"Spa Treatment"},{"time":"wwww","desc":"Shopping"}]};
```

I have no trouble accessing the friends[0].name, friends[0].color etc. values.

I use this command to store the friends array in localStorage:

localStorage.setItem("allFriendInfo",JSON.stringify(friends));

Upon inspection in Chrome Developer Tools "Resources", I see the string stored as:

```
[{"name":"Fred","color":"rgb(255, 0, 0)","entries":"[{\"time\":\"xxxx\",\"desc\":\"Party\"},{\"time\":\"yyyy\",\"desc\":\"Shopping\"},{\"time\":\"zzzz\",\"desc\":\"Dinner\"}]"},{"name":"George","color":"rgb(0, 255, 0)","entries":":"[{\"time\":\"qqqq\",\"desc\":\"Car Pool\"},{\"time\":\"vvvv\",\"desc\":\"Spa Treatment\"},{\"time\":\"wwww\",\"desc":\"Shopping\"}]"}]
```

I read that from local storage with JSON.parse:

```
friends = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("allFriendInfo"));
```

I am able to access the stored data with "friend[0]" which appears like this in the alert:

```
friends[0] = {"name":"Fred","color":"rgb(255, 0, 0)","entries":"[{"time":"xxxx","desc":"Party"},{"time":"yyyy","desc":"Shopping"},{"time":"zzzz","desc":"Dinner"}]"}
```

and

```
alert(friends.length);
```

returns a value equal to the number of items in the array.

but I can't get

```
friends[0].name
```

to return the value of the "name" property, and haven't been able to get as far as processing the list of "entries" in the object.

EDIT: after removing the quotes, I can get the value friends[0].name etc. but I can't get any joy from friends[0].entries.time or similar.

Thanks in advance to any "real" programmers that can help this novice out.

Comment: show us more, specifically the part that saves and loads. if you stringify before save and parse after load, you should have your objects back.

Comment: Have you tried assigning `friend[0]` to a variable?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please take the [Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: Yes, I have tried assigning friends[0] to a variable called "obj" then trying "obj.name" and still nothing.

Comment: What does `console.log(friends)` give?

Comment: Why are you assigning strings of JSON to the `friends` elements?  Remove the `''` and you'll assign real objects, which are much more manageable.

Comment: I think the example above is just one of the last incarnations I tried. I did try without the '' around the object, and now I'm able to get the objects into an array but can't read the "entries" object array.

Comment: It occurred to me that if I store the two "main" properties (name / color) in one array, and have a second array for the "entries" then I can reference them in parallel rather than trying to mine out the JSON string as a "sub object". I will write back if that works for me, but since all it means is adding a second array when the info is loaded or saved, that shouldn't be too onerous.

Comment: Thanks James I fixed the problem with the quotes, and I did decide to just use two separate arrays of objects rather than trying to nest an object array inside another object. It's working fine: whatever index I'm using I just refer to both arrays with the same index and robert is your father's brother.